# How to filter pageBlockTable rows without modifying the source list?

Tags: pageblocktable, table

Title says it all.

Similar to `<apex:pageBlockTable first={!first} rows={!rows}/>` OOTB attributes which filters rows based on index, I'm trying to find an **OOTB solution** for rendering only specific rows which match **text** filter criteria. For example: selecting `Department picklist = Audit` will show **Audit** professionals only in the pageBlockTable.

My current non-OOTB solution is to change the pageBlockTable's **source list** to `value={!subsetList}` and update a **master list** accordingly (whenever any textbox values or checkboxes in the table are changed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is non-OOTB and EASY.

Maintain a MASTER LIST separately in the controller. And tie a subset list to the `pageBlockTable VALUE="{!subsetList}"`.

Upon filter change (selectOption change) on the UI,

- simply assign a `new List<Wrapper/sObject>()` to the subsetList
- create a new subsetList from the master list by a for-loop and using the `.add()` method for master list items which are equal to the filter.

*Apparently*, this is a shallow copy.

*(Shallow copy is immensely beneficial. Example:
Inputcheckbox/inputfield changes on a FILTERED pageBlock table (`value="{!subsetList}`) **automatically** reflects in the master list variable in the controller.)*

Answer (score 1):

Good question, I don't think there is OOTB solution for that.

[`apex:pageBlockTable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm) just represents a Salesforce styled table. Like in HTML table you would need to do your own filtering in Server.

You can maybe use a [Hierarchical custom setting](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/08/using-hierarchy-custom-settings-in-salesforce-com/) which display filters out results based on specified value(s).

For better performance, Use [JavaScript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm) or [Remote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects.htm), instead value/rerender attributes or actionSupport/function.

Comment: Just to add up another argument to @Rahul's answer. Is strongly reccommended to do that kind of filtering, server side, since that is the way in which the MVC pattern should work. The view(presented by the pageblocktable in this case), should be concerned only on printing data, not in any other logic, that decides which records to show and which not. I know, it's not your answer, but take it more as a suggestion.